# jQuery validator for password

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```
$("#register-form").validate({
    rules: {
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
        },
        confirm_password: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: {
                param: "#password",
                depends: function (element) {
                    //console.log($('#password').valid());
                    return $('#password').valid();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I'm having an issue with the confirm password, may be in the plugin itself.
Having the following step: (Also found issue with vice versa)
1. Enter password.
2. Enter confirm-password with error.  (Leave as it is)
3. Enter password which match with confirm password.

Now try to match both. The confirm password still have error, though both same.

I also trying to validate it manually **$('#confirm_password').valid()**
Still it returns true. (Because it matches with the previous value that matched)

Help me around the same.

Comment: The question is about jQuery validator https://jqueryvalidation.org

Comment: please share html

Comment: There's nothing to do with HTML. It's quite simple code.

Comment: so, you know the html is correct, okay, we're not going to look at it

Comment: It's entirely unclear why you think you need to make the `equalTo` rule depend upon validity of the first field.   It makes no sense.  The second field must always be equal to the first so there's no need to toggle this rule!

Comment: Not only might you have an error in the markup, we're asking for your HTML so nobody has to rewrite it from scratch when testing a possible solution. The burden is on you to write a good question that includes enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Sparky, this is a duplicate one, but does not sufficient for my answer.
I still don't know why you mess with HTML.
For your comfortablity I have create fiddle here. 
https://jsfiddle.net/qj4qLafk/1/
Hope to save it in your local and test it...
Thanks